# No puedo generar el APK en Android Studio Flamingo patch 2

Tags: android, apk

Estoy tratando de generar mi apk pero me sale este error

> Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in C:\Users\user\Documents\AndroidStudioProjects\Nombre_Proyecto\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt.

Ya intente con varias respuestas que encontré en esta pagina pero nada me funciona.

¿Cómo lo puedo resolver?

Agrego el gradel

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.inventarioscyp.mobile_manager'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.5.2'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.inventarioscyp.mobile_manager'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //Libreria para conectarse a la base de datos
    implementation files('libs/jtds-1.3.1.jar')
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    //Librearias para crear el codigo QR
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
    //Libreria para poder colocar un Progress bar cuando tarde la operación
    //https://github.com/dybarsky/spots-dialogL
    //implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
}
```

Comment: Agrega tus build.gradle por favor.